# Is there a way to increase the thickness of the axes in all the graphs of subplots in matplotlib, Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to increase the thickness of all the graphs in the subplots arranged in 3x1 fashion. Using some previous block/thread in this website I found that something this works for a single graph, I tried this also, but unfortunately it is increasing the thickness of a single subplot instead of all the subplots

```
ax = fig1.gca()
for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
  ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(1.5)
```

Could any one please comment/suggest anything. Thanks in advance

Comment: @BigBen Thanks a lot for your quick response. Should I loop over this command to the subplots? Sorry could you kindly elaborate how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
fig1, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1)

for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    ax1.spines[axis].set_linewidth(1.5)
    ax2.spines[axis].set_linewidth(1.5)
    ax3.spines[axis].set_linewidth(1.5)
```